# How can I write formulas with conditions and spill in Excel (IF plus FILTER)?

Tags: excel, filter, spill-range

I’m trying to use the FILTER formula in Excel to return all values from a column that meet three possible conditions:

```
If column D equals "CDI" or equals "SELIC", return the value from column K;
Otherwise, return 0
```

But I need this formula to be dynamic in the number of rows, in the style of spill functions. I’m not able to create an IF formula that meets my needs.

The filter function I’m applying is this:

```
=FILTER(D:D;(D:D="CDI")+(D:D="SELIC"))
```

Is it possible to combine it with the IF function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=IF((FILTER(D:D,D:D<>"")="CDI")+(FILTER(D:D,D:D<>"")="SELIC");FILTER(K:K,D:D<>"");0)`?

Comment: Thanks!! I'll check soon. I'm still struggling to understand the properties of these "spill" functions. So, for each element of the function, I'd need to repeat the whole filter? Is there a way to create a name or another form of shortcut? If I need to use this approach, I predict very large functions ahead...